# ER Model representing entities not stored in DB and user choice

Tags: entity-relationship

I'm trying to create a ER diagram of a simple retail chain type database model. You have your customer, the various stores, inventory etc.

My first question is, how to represent a customer placing an order in a store. If the customer is a discount card holder, the company has their name, address etc, so I can have a cardHolder entity connect to item and store with an order relationship. But how do I represent an order being placed by a customer who is not really an entity in the database?

Secondly, how are conditional... stuff represented in ER diagrams, e.g. in a car dealership, a customer may choose one or more optional extra when buying a car. I would think that there is a Car entity with the relevant attributes and the options as a multi-valued attribute, but how do you represent a user picking those options (I.e. order table shows the car ordered, extras chosen and the added cost of extras) in the order relationship?

Answer (score 1):

First, do you really need to model customers as distinct entities, or do you just need order, payment and delivery details? Many retail systems don't track individual customers. If you need to, you can have a customer table with a surrogate key and unique constraints on identifying attributes like SSN or discount card number (even if those attributes are optional). It's generally hard to prevent duplication in customer tables since there's no ideal natural key for people, so consider whether this is really required.

How to model optional extras depends on what they depends on. Some extras might be make or model-specific, e.g. the choice of certain colors or manual/automatic transmission. Extended warranties might be available across the board.

Here's an example of car-specific optional extras:

```
car (car_id PK, make, model, color, vin, price, ...)
car_extras (extra_id PK, car_id FK, option_name, price)
order (order_id PK, date_time, car_id FK, customer_id FK, payment_id FK, discount)
order_extras (order_id PK/FK, car_id FK, extra_id PK/FK)
```

I excluded price totals since those can be calculated via aggregate queries.

In my example, `order_extras.car_id` is redundant, but supports better integrity via the use of composite FK constraints (i.e. `(order_id, car_id)` references the corresponding columns in `order`, and `(car_id, extra_id)` references the corresponding columns in `car_optional_extras` to prevent invalid extras from being linked to an order).

Here's an ER diagram for the tables above:

[image: Car orders with optional extras ER diagram]

Answer (score 0):

First, as per your thought you can definitely have two kinds of customers.  Discount card holders whose details are present with the company and new customers whose details aren't available with the company.

There are three possible ways to achieve what you are trying,
1) Have two different order table in the system(which I personally wouldn't suggest)
2) Have a single Order table in the system and getting the details of those who are a discount card holder.
3) Insert a row in the discount card holder table for new/unregistered customers having only one order table in the system.

Having a single order table would make the system standardized and would be more convenient while performing many other operations.

Secondly, to solve your concern, you need to follow normalization.  It will reduce the current problem faced and will also make the system redundant free and will make the entities light weighted which will directly impact on the performance when you grow large.

The extra chosen items can be listed in the order against the customer by adding it at the time of generating a bill using foreign key.  Dealing with keys will result in fast and robust results instead of storing redundant/repeating details at various places.

By following normalization, the problem can be handled by applying foreign keys wherever you want to refer data to avoid problems or errors.

Preferably NF 4 would be better.  Have a look at the following link for getting started with normalization.

http://www.w3schools.in/dbms/database-normalization/